# How do I get rid of circular numbers in my list

Tags: c#, console-application

Okay, I know that this code is crude, and all around a messy, but I am no programmer, so bear with me. I have this code that lists a bunch of numbers, but I want it to not list any circular copies of the numbers.

<s>For example, if the number 111262 is on my list, I don't want 112621, 126211, 262111, 621112, or 211126 to be listed.</s>

**Sorry, that number cannot be on the list.**

For a *true* example, if the number 111252 is on my list, I don't want 112521, 125211, 252111, 521112, or 211125 to be listed.

Any help is appreciated!

```
namespace Toric_Classes
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number_of_perms=0;
        bool badsubsum1;
        bool badsubsum2;
        int subsum1 = 0;
        int subsum2 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int class_length=6;
        int[] toric_class=new int[class_length];
        // The nested for loops scroll through every possible number of length class_length, where each digit can have a value of 1,2,..., or class_length-1
        // Each number is looked at as an array, and is not stored anywhere, only printed if it satisfies certain conditions
        for(int i1=1; i1<class_length; i1++)
        {
            toric_class[0] = i1;
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 < class_length; i2++)
            {
                toric_class[1] = i2;
                for (int i3 = 1; i3 < class_length; i3++)
                {
                    toric_class[2] = i3;
                    for (int i4 = 1; i4 < class_length; i4++)
                    {
                        toric_class[3] = i4;
                        for (int i5 = 1; i5 < class_length; i5++)
                        {
                            toric_class[4] = i5;
                            for (int i6 = 1; i6 < class_length; i6++)
                            {
                                badsubsum1 = false;
                                badsubsum2 = false;
                                toric_class[5] = i6;
                                // Find the value of the sum of the digits of our array.
                                // We only want numbers that have a total digit sum being a multiple of class_length
                                for (int k = 0; k < class_length; k++)
                                {
                                    sum += toric_class[k];
                                }
                                // The follwong two nested loops find the value of every contiguous subsum of our number, but not the total subsum.
                                // We *do not* want any subsum to be a multiple of class_length.
                                // That is, if our number is, say, 121342, we want to find 1+2, 1+2+1, 1+2+1+3, 1+2+1+3+4, 2+1, 2+1+3, 2+1+3+4, 2+1+3+4+2, 1+3, 1+3+4, 1+3+4+2, 3+4, 3+4+2, and 4+2
                                // The following checks 1+2, 1+2+1, 1+2+1+3, 1+2+1+3+4, 2+1, 2+1+3, 2+1+3+4, 1+3, 1+3+4, and 3+4
                                for (int i = 0; i < class_length - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    for (int j = i + 1; j < class_length - 1; j++)
                                    {
                                        for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
                                        {
                                            subsum1 += toric_class[k];
                                        }
                                        if (subsum1 % class_length == 0)
                                        {
                                            badsubsum1 = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        subsum1 = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                                // The following checks 2+1, 2+1+3, 2+1+3+4, 2+1+3+4+2, 1+3, 1+3+4, 1+3+4+2, 3+4, 3+4+2, and 4+2
                                for (int i = 1; i < class_length; i++)
                                {
                                    for (int j = i + 1; j < class_length; j++)
                                    {
                                        for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
                                        {
                                            subsum2 += toric_class[k];
                                        }
                                        if (subsum2 % class_length == 0)
                                        {
                                            badsubsum2 = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        subsum2 = 0;
                                    }
                                }
                                // We only want numbers that satisfies the following conditions
                                if (sum % class_length == 0 && badsubsum1 == false && badsubsum2 == false)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in toric_class)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write(item.ToString());
                                    }
                                    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                                    number_of_perms++;
                                }
                                sum = 0;
                                subsum1 = 0;
                                subsum2 = 0;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Permuatations: "+number_of_perms);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, I am creating a list of all numbers with length n that satisfy certain conditions. Consider the number d1d2...dn, where each di is a digit of our number. Each di may have value 1,2,...,n. Our number is in the list if it satisfies the following

1. The sum of all the digits is a multiple of n, that is,

   d1+d2+...+dn = 0 mod n
2. Every contiguous subsum of the digits *is not* a multiple of n, aside from the total sum, that is, if i !=1 and j != n, then

   di+d(i+1)+...+dj != 0 mod n

I should mention again that a "number" does not strictly use the numbers 0-9 in its digits. It may take any value between 1 and n. In my code, I am using the case where n=6.

The code works by creating an array of length `class_length` (in the code above, I use `class_length=6`). We first have 6 nested for loops that simply assign values to the array `toric_class`. The first `for` assigns `toric_class[0]`, the second `for` assigns `toric_class[1]`, and so on. In the first go around, we are generating the array `111111`, then `111112`, up to `111115`, then  `111121`, etc. So essentially, we are looking at all heximal numbers that do not include 0. Once we reach our sixth value in our array, we check the array `toric_class` and check its values to ensure that it satisfies the above conditions. If it does, we simply print the array in a line, and move on.

Comment: does it have to be efficient? seems easy to do with strings but might be kind of slow. For example `if (("123" + "123").Contains("312"))`

Comment: @Slai have you seen my answer? It considers that. I just can't see how program should operate because of these 6-depth fors in OP post.

Comment: @Bonnaduck could you please comment your code in the question?

Comment: Check out my modified answer using circular linked list, which result in `Dictionary<int,Hashset<int>>` as the final result, thus enabling a quick search of the repetitions

Comment: @Bonnaduck What should happen with numbers containing zeroes? Using 620 as an example, the circular numbers are 206 and 062, but leading zeroes get ignored so 062 = 62. Should 62 be excluded as a circular number or not?

Comment: @slavanap I hope I added enough information

Comment: @swatsonpicken I edited the question to clarify. 0 will never be a value. If we are looking at numbers with n digits, each digit will have a value of 1 through n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my easy and inefficient way that should work with minimal changes to your code. It requires shared string list `var strList = new List<string>();` to store the used numbers. Then this part:

```
foreach (var item in toric_class)
{
    Console.Write(item.ToString());
}
Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
number_of_perms++;
```

becomes something like this:

```
string strItem = " " + string.Join(" ", toric_class) + " "; // Example: int[] {1, 12, 123} becomes " 1 12 123 "

if (!strList.Any(str => str.Contains(strItem))) // Example: if " 1 12 123 1 12 123 " contains " 1 12 123 "
{
    Console.WriteLine(strItem);

    strItem += strItem.Substring(1); // double the string, but keep only one space between them
    strList.Add(strItem);
}

number_of_perms++; // not sure if this should be in the if statement
```

---

The idea is that for example the string `" 1 1 1 2 5 2 1 1 1 2 5 2 "` contains all circular copies of the numbers `{1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2}`. I used string as a lazy way to check if array contains sub-array, but you can use similar approach to store copy of the used numbers in a list of arrays `new List<int[]>()` and check if any of the arrays in the list is circular copy of the current array, or even better `HashSet<int[]>()` approach similar to @slavanap's answer.

---

The [first version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41681145/1) was the easiest, but it works only with array of single digit items.

`List` is almost the same as array (`new List<string>()` instead of `new string[]`), but makes it much easier and efficient to add items to it. For example `{1,2}.Add(3)` becomes `{1,2,3}`.

`str => str.Contains(strItem)` is shortcut for a function that accepts parameter `str` and returns the result of `str.Contains(strItem)`. That "function" is then passed to the [`.Any`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6a1af7c3d17845e3) LINQ extension, so

```
strList.Any(str => str.Contains(strItem))
```

is shortcut for something like this:

```
foreach(string str in strList)
{
    if (str.Contains(strItem)) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: This works perfectly (just a missing parenthesis). A bit embarrassing to admit, but i don't exactly understand how the code works, but the method you explain makes perfect sense. I'll have read up on the details. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bonnaduck Thanks. It's fine, because I don't understand most of your code and math explanation :). You can ask me on the parts that you can't understand, because changing the code without understanding it seems risky, and learning LINQ is very useful (I am guessing the `.Any` part is the most confusing).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.Any`, `.Add`, or `.Insert`, but yes, the `.Any` does seem to be the most complex part.

Answer (score 1):

That's where OOP really benefits. Comments inlined.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3 {

    struct MyInt : IEquatable<MyInt> {
        private int _value;

        public MyInt(int value) {
            _value = value;
        }

        // make it look like int
        static public implicit operator MyInt(int value) {
            return new MyInt(value);
        }
        public static explicit operator int(MyInt instance) {
            return instance._value;
        }

        // main difference in these 3 methods
        private int GetDigitsNum() {
            int temp, res;
            for (res = 0, temp = Math.Abs(_value); temp > 0; ++res, temp /= 10);
            return res;
        }
        public bool Equals(MyInt other) {
            int digits = other.GetDigitsNum();
            if (digits != this.GetDigitsNum())
                return false;
            int temp = other._value;

            // prepare mul used in shifts
            int mul = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < digits - 1; ++i)
                mul *= 10;

            // compare
            for (int i = 0; i < digits; ++i) {
                if (temp == _value)
                    return true;
                // ROR
                int t = temp % 10;
                temp = temp / 10 + t * mul;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            // hash code must be equal for "equal" items,
            // that's why use a sum of digits.
            int sum = 0;
            for (int temp = _value; temp > 0; temp /= 10)
                sum += temp % 10;
            return sum;
        }

        // be consistent
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            return (obj is MyInt) ? Equals((MyInt)obj) : false;
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return _value.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            List<MyInt> list = new List<MyInt> { 112621, 126211, 262111, 621112, 211126 };
            // make a set of unique items from list
            HashSet<MyInt> set = new HashSet<MyInt>(list);

            // print that set    
            foreach(int item in set)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Output:
   112621

Comment: This does not work according to the OPs requirements. The logic you have provided would regard 121216 as being valid, but the OP is looking to identify only the _circular_ numbers, not those that happen to contain the same elements as the number under test.

Comment: @swatsonpicken Have you tried the code? Please look at "ROR" comment, where numbers shifted right circularily for comparison.

Comment: I was looking only at the `GetHashCode` and forgot to check the `Equals`. It looks like it would work. `Equals` seems like it would return false for `int` and other numeric types but I guess not an issue because the `<MyInt>` type of the collections. I still can't figure out if OP is trying to find all permutations or something else. OP mentioned that he is not programmer, so I don't think he can figure out how to try the code without knowing what it does.

Comment: @slavanp My apologies. The example data in the original question regarded 112621 as an invalid value. I didn't pay attention to the fact that your solution uses slightly different test data.

Comment: @slavanap it seems like one of those unclear questions where you put a lot of effort for very little reward to give correct answer to possibly a wrong question. Your answer seems like the most efficient one, but i just noticed that you calculate the number of digits two times per comparison, so seems better to calculate and store it only once in the constructor.

Comment: @Slai yes, it could be optimized a lot. I just provided general OOP solution. You should also consider doing `if (_value == other._value) return true;` at the first line of `Equals`. Btw, related to your prev.comment. I don't need to make explicit `public override bool Equals(object obj)` implementation for `int` support, because I have `public static _explicit_ operator int(MyInt instance)`

Answer (score 1):

The following method:

```
private static List<int> GetCircularEquivalents(int value)
{
    var circularList = new List<int>();
    var valueString = value.ToString();
    var length = valueString.Length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        valueString = valueString.Substring(1, length) + valueString.Substring(0, 1);
        circularList.Add(int.Parse(valueString));
    }

    return circularList;
}
```

will return a list of the circular numbers derived from the input value. Using your example, this method can be called like this:

```
var circularList = GetCircularEquivalents(111262);
var dirtyList = new List<int> { 1, 112621, 2, 126211, 3, 262111, 4, 621112, 5, 211126, 6 };
var cleanList = dirtyList.Except(circularList).ToList();
```

which would result in a cleanList made up of the numbers 1 through 6, i.e. the dirtyList with all the circular numbers derived from 111262 removed.

Comment: I edited the question to make some clarifications. The number is stored as an array (as I would like to eventually generalize, and the digits of my number may eventually take a value greater than 9). Is there a way to change this method so that it will take an array?