# Creating all possible arrays without nested for loops

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I would like to generate all the possible numbers that have length `n` and each digit of my number has a value from the set `{1,2,...,n-1}`, as an array. In other words, I would like to list all the base `n` numbers with length `n` that do not include `0`.

Right now, the only way I can think to do it is by nesting n `for` loops, and assigning `myArray[i]` with the (i+1)th loop, i.e.

```
int n;
int[] myArray = new int[n];
for (int i1 = 1; i1 < n; i1++)
    myArray[0]=i1;
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 < n; i2++)
        myArray[1]=i2;
        // and so on....
            for (int in = 1; in < n; in++)
            {
                myArray[n]=in;
                foreach (var item in myArray)
                    Console.Write(item.ToString());
                    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

and then printing each array at the innermost loop. The obvious issue is that for each n, I need to manually write `n` `for` loops.

From what I've read, recursion seems to be the best way to replace nested `for` loops, but I can't seem figure out how to make a general method for recursion either.

**EDIT**

For example, if `n=3`, I would like to write out `1 1 1`, `1 1 2`, `1 2 1`, `1 2 2`, `2 1 1`, `2 1 2`, `2 2 1`, `2 2 2`.

We are not limited to `n<11`. For example, if `n=11`, we would output

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3
...
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3
...
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 10
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 10 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 10 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 10 3
...
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 1
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 2
...
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

So, a digit of a number may be any value between and including `1` and `10`. The array `myArray` is simply used to get one of these numbers, then we print it, and go on to the next number and repeat.

Comment: the first problem you have in your code is that you use an array of `n` elements (to store all possible values you are looking for, I assume), but the number of values you need to find is much higher (in the order of `n!` or `(n-1) * (n-1)`, if I understand your question)

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a bit?  Expected input and output?  Your code doesn't make a ton of sense for any interpretation I can think of based on your problem as stated, but your problem as stated isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: I'm guessing `n` can be at most `10`, otherwise I'm not sure how *one* digit can have a value of the set.

Comment: @GianPaolo Each entry of the array only holds one digit of the number. That number is printed, and we then add one to the last entry of the array and print.

@DanField Does the edit help to clarify?

@InBetween No, a "digit" may have a value of more than `10`. Similarly to how hexidecimal uses `A=10`, `B=11`, and so on.

Comment: `IEnumerable<int[]> f(int n) => Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Range(1, n-1), n).Aggregate((IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>)new[] {new int[0]}, (a, b) => a.SelectMany(c => b, (d, e) => d.Concat(new[] {e}))).Select(a => a.ToArray());`

Comment: @GianPaolo its much higher than that: `(n - 1) ^ n`.

Comment: @DanField a bit more info in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653050/how-do-i-get-rid-of-circular-numbers-in-my-list)

Comment: @InBetween you're right, the question was not so clear before the last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, when thinking in recursive solutions, try to solve the problem using immutable structures; everything is much simpler to understand.

So first of all, lets build ourselves a fast little immutable stack that will help us keep track of the number we are currently generating (while not worrying about what other numbers are being generated in the recursive call...remember, immutable data can't change!):

```
public class ImmutableStack<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly ImmutableStack<T> Empty = new ImmutableStack<T>();
    private readonly T first;
    private readonly ImmutableStack<T> rest;

    public int Count { get; }

    private ImmutableStack()
    {
        Count = 0;
    }

    private ImmutableStack(T first, ImmutableStack<T> rest)
    {
        Debug.Assert(rest != null);

        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
        Count = rest.Count + 1;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var current = this;

        while (current != Empty)
        {
            yield return current.first;
            current = current.rest;
        }
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not peek an empty stack.");

        return first;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Pop()
    {
        if (this == Empty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not pop an empty stack.");

        return rest;
    }

    public ImmutableStack<T> Push(T item) => new ImmutableStack<T>(item, this);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

That's easy. Note how the stack reuses data. How many empty immutable structs will there be in our little program? Only one. And stacks containing the sequence `1->2->4`? Yup, only one.

Now, we implement a recursive function that just keeps adding numbers to the stack until we reach our "bail out" condition. Which is? When the stack contains `n` elements. Easy peasy:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> generateNumbers(ImmutableStack<string> digits, IEnumerable<string> set, int length)
{
    if (digits.Count == length)
    {
        yield return int.Parse(string.Concat(digits));
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var digit in set)
        {
            var newDigits = digits.Push(digit);

            foreach (var newNumber in generateNumbers(newDigits, set, length))
            {
                yield return newNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, and now we just need to tie it alltogether with our public method:

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> GenerateNumbers(int length)
 {
     if (length < 1)
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));

     return generateNumbers(ImmutableStack<string>.Empty,
                            Enumerable.Range(1, length - 1).Select(d => d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                            length);
 }
```

And sure enough, if we call this thing:

```
 var ns = GenerateNumbers(3);
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                               ns.Select((n, index) => $"[{index + 1}]\t: {n}")));
```

We get the expected output:

```
[1]     : 111
[2]     : 211
[3]     : 121
[4]     : 221
[5]     : 112
[6]     : 212
[7]     : 122
[8]     : 222
```

Do note that the total amount of numbers generated of a specified length `n` is `(n - 1) ^ n` which means that for relatively small values of `length` you are going to get quite an amount of numbers generated; `n = 10` generates 3 486 784 401...