# Change this nested for loop to recursion

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, recursion

I posted [this similar, previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684152/creating-all-possible-arrays-without-nested-for-loops), but I was not very clear.

I have the following code:

```
int N=4;
int[] myArray = new int[N];
for (int i1 = 1; i1 < N; i1++)
    myArray[0]=i1;
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 < N; i2++)
        myArray[1]=i2;
            for (int i3 = 1; i3 < N; i3++)
                myArray[2]=i3;
                for (int i4 = 1; i4 < N; i4++)
                {
                    myArray[3]=i4;

                    foreach (var item in myArray)
                        Console.Write(item.ToString());
                    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
```

This outputs the following:

```
1111
1112
1113
1121
1122
1123
1131
....
3332
3333
```

Is there a simple way to change this nested `for` loop to recursion? I am not very skilled at programming, so the simpler, the better. I am not worried about how efficient the code is.

I, effectively, would like to be able to change the int `N` in my code to different numbers, without having to add or remove anything from my code.

**EDIT**

Here is what I have so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int class_length = 4;
            int[] toric_class = Enumerable.Repeat(1, class_length).ToArray();
            Recursion(toric_class, class_length, 1, 3);

            Console.Read();
        }
        static void Recursion(int[] toric_class, int length, int number, int spot)
        {
            if (number < 4)
            {
                toric_class[spot] = number;
                foreach (var item in toric_class)
                {
                    Console.Write(item.ToString());
                }
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                Recursion(toric_class, length, number + 1, spot);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This only outputs

```
1111
1112
1113
```

I am unsure of where to go from here.

Comment: homework? apart of that, your construction with 5 loops looks not well designed. instead of thinking about a recursion (remember stack overflow), you could think about data structures.

Comment: You should have editing the previous question so it could be reopened.  I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @mnemonic No, not homework, simply working on this for my own benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Set(int[] array, int index, int N)
{
    if (index == N)
    {
        foreach (var item in array)
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        array[index] = i;
        Set(array, index + 1, N);
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
int N = 4;
int[] myArray = new int[N];
Set(myArray, 0, N);
```

Comment: This works great (just need to change `if (index == 4)` to `== N`) , and I believe I understand it fully. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Yes, my mistake, with 4, have corrected it, you are wekcome.

Comment: I deleted the comment, as I found a way around it. But now I understand why it didn't work. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to *simplify* and *generalize* the solition, you don't want any recursion:

```
// N - length of the array
// K - kind of radix; items of the array will be in [1..K] range
private static IEnumerable<int[]> Generator(int N = 4, int K = 3) {
  int[] items = Enumerable
    .Repeat(1, N)
    .ToArray();

  do {
    yield return items.ToArray(); // .ToArray() : let's return a copy of the array

    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (items[i] < K) {
        items[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
      else
        items[i] = 1;
  }
  while (!items.All(item => item == 1)); 
}
```

Test

```
string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator(4)
  .Select(items => string.Concat(items)));

Console.Write(test);
```

Outcome:

```
1111
1112
1113
1121
1122
...
3321
3322
3323
3331
3332
3333
```

Comment: Might I ask why we do not want any recursion?

Comment: @Bonnaduck: in case `N` is *large*, you can well have a *deep* recoursion, and *run out of stack*.